# Man in the middle attack

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing

How data can be modified in a man in the middle attack? is there any video demonstrating that,any how to guide,i need practical material ,i have used cain and abel,ettercap  but now i am strucked i don't know how to move furthur.
I am  able to see the packets but, how do i modify them.please help me.

Note:-I am working on mini project where i have to simulate the Man-in-the-Middle attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For web based application: you can use MiTM proxy such as: OWASP ZAP Proxy and mitm (written in python). First you must configure your web browser to connect using this proxy. Then you can intercept and modify each requests and responses.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for that.

Comment: @Gopal For OWASP ZAP Proxy, you may check this [youtube playlist](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH0RBI0nmww&list=PLEBitBW-Hlsv8cEIUntAO8st2UGhmrjUB)